# Xcode / iOS app: How to get url parameters of webview? (wrapped pwa)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, progressive-web-apps

I've built a single page PWA with bubble.io and generated the xcode project with PWAbuilder.
I'm now trying to setup OneSignal. I need to extract a URL parameter from the PWA that is inside webview.
But when running the app on my iPhone, I can see in the xcode console that any change in the URL doesn't get detected. It only prints the main url once and it doesn't change when I navigate.

Here is the webview.swift file

Thanks for your help!

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import AuthenticationServices
import SafariServices


func createWebView(container: UIView, WKSMH: WKScriptMessageHandler, WKND: WKNavigationDelegate, NSO: NSObject, VC: ViewController) -> WKWebView{
    
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let userContentController = WKUserContentController()

    userContentController.add(WKSMH, name: "print")
    userContentController.add(WKSMH, name: "push-subscribe")
    userContentController.add(WKSMH, name: "push-permission-request")
    userContentController.add(WKSMH, name: "push-permission-state")
    config.userContentController = userContentController
    
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        config.limitsNavigationsToAppBoundDomains = true;
        
    }
    config.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    config.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "standalone")
    
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: calcWebviewFrame(webviewView: container, toolbarView: nil), configuration: config)
    setCustomCookie(webView: webView)
    webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    webView.isHidden = true;
    webView.navigationDelegate = WKND;
    webView.scrollView.bounces = false;
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    webView.configuration.applicationNameForUserAgent = "Safari/604.1" // See https://github.com/pwa-builder/pwabuilder-ios/issues/30
    webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1";    
    webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    webView.addObserver(NSO, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
    
    return webView
}

func setAppStoreAsReferrer(contentController: WKUserContentController) {
    let scriptSource = "document.referrer = `app-info://platform/ios-store`;"
    let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptSource, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    contentController.addUserScript(script);
}

func setCustomCookie(webView: WKWebView) {
    let _platformCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
        .domain: rootUrl.host!,
        .path: "/",
        .name: platformCookie.name,
        .value: platformCookie.value,
        .secure: "FALSE",
        .expires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 31556926)
    ])!

    webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(_platformCookie)

}

func calcWebviewFrame(webviewView: UIView, toolbarView: UIToolbar?) -> CGRect{
    if ((toolbarView) != nil) {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: toolbarView!.frame.height, width: webviewView.frame.width, height: webviewView.frame.height - toolbarView!.frame.height)
    }
    else {
        let winScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
        let windowScene = winScene as! UIWindowScene
        var statusBarHeight = windowScene.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
        
        switch displayMode {
        case "fullscreen":
            #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
                if let titlebar = windowScene.titlebar {
                    titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden
                    titlebar.toolbar = nil
                }
            #endif
            return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: webviewView.frame.width, height: webviewView.frame.height)
        default:
            #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
            statusBarHeight = 29
            #endif
            let windowHeight = webviewView.frame.height - statusBarHeight
            return CGRect(x: 0, y: statusBarHeight, width: webviewView.frame.width, height: windowHeight)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: WKUIDelegate {
    // redirect new tabs to main webview
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        if (navigationAction.targetFrame == nil) {
            webView.load(navigationAction.request)
        }
        return nil
    }
    // restrict navigation to target host, open external links in 3rd party apps
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if (navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "about") {
            return decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
        if let requestUrl = navigationAction.request.url{
            if let requestHost = requestUrl.host {
                let matchingHostOrigin = allowedOrigins.first(where: { requestHost.range(of: $0) != nil })
                if (matchingHostOrigin != nil) {
                    // Open in main webview
                    decisionHandler(.allow)
                    if (!toolbarView.isHidden) {
                        toolbarView.isHidden = true
                        webView.frame = calcWebviewFrame(webviewView: webviewView, toolbarView: nil)
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    let matchingAuthOrigin = authOrigins.first(where: { requestHost.range(of: $0) != nil })
                    if (matchingAuthOrigin != nil) {
                        decisionHandler(.allow)
                        if (toolbarView.isHidden) {
                            toolbarView.isHidden = false
                            webView.frame = calcWebviewFrame(webviewView: webviewView, toolbarView: toolbarView)
                        }
                        return
                    }
                    else {
                        if (navigationAction.navigationType == .other &&
                            navigationAction.value(forKey: "syntheticClickType") as! Int == 0 &&
                            (navigationAction.targetFrame != nil)
                        ) {
                            decisionHandler(.allow)
                            return
                        }
                        else {
                            decisionHandler(.cancel)
                        }
                    }
                    

                    if ["http", "https"].contains(requestUrl.scheme?.lowercased() ?? "") {
                         // Can open with SFSafariViewController
                         let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: requestUrl)
                         self.present(safariViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                     } else {
                         // Scheme is not supported or no scheme is given, use openURL
                        if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(requestUrl)) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(requestUrl)
                        }
                     }
                    
                }
            } else {
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                if (navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "tel" || navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "mailto" ){
                    if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(requestUrl)) {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(requestUrl)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        }
        
    }
    // Handle javascript: `window.alert(message: String)`
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
        runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String,
        initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
        completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        // Set the message as the UIAlertController message
        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: nil,
            message: message,
            preferredStyle: .alert
        )

        // Add a confirmation action “OK”
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: .default,
            handler: { _ in
                // Call completionHandler
                completionHandler()
            }
        )
        alert.addAction(okAction)

        // Display the NSAlert
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    // Handle javascript: `window.confirm(message: String)`
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
        runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String,
        initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
        completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

        // Set the message as the UIAlertController message
        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: nil,
            message: message,
            preferredStyle: .alert
        )
        
        // Add a confirmation action “Cancel”
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "Cancel",
            style: .cancel,
            handler: { _ in
                // Call completionHandler
                completionHandler(false)
            }
        )
        
        // Add a confirmation action “OK”
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: .default,
            handler: { _ in
                // Call completionHandler
                completionHandler(true)
            }
        )
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        alert.addAction(okAction)

        // Display the NSAlert
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    // Handle javascript: `window.prompt(prompt: String, defaultText: String?)`
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
        runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String,
        defaultText: String?,
        initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
        completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

        // Set the message as the UIAlertController message
        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: nil,
            message: prompt,
            preferredStyle: .alert
        )
        
        // Add a confirmation action “Cancel”
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "Cancel",
            style: .cancel,
            handler: { _ in
                // Call completionHandler
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        )
        
        // Add a confirmation action “OK”
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: .default,
            handler: { _ in
                // Call completionHandler with Alert input
                if let input = alert.textFields?.first?.text {
                    completionHandler(input)
                }
            }
        )
        
        alert.addTextField { textField in
            textField.placeholder = defaultText
        }
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        alert.addAction(okAction)

        // Display the NSAlert
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a solution but I couldn't find it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an observer for the url.

```
webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let key = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] {
         print("value \(key)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! Is there a specific part of the code where I should add this? I'm getting 2 errors: "Cannot find 'self' in scope" and "'override' can only be specified on class members"